# How do I make a combobox selection changes do a calculation in C#

Tags: c#, combobox, textbox

What I am trying to do is , I have made a Unit Converter. It has 2 comboBoxes (**fromCb** and **toCB** )and 2 Textboxes (**fromTb** and **toTb** ). What I want to do is for example if I select **Kilometers** in **fromCB** and enter a value in **fromTB** , and when I select **Meters** in **toCB** , I want the value to be calculated and shown in **toTB** as soon as I select **Meters** in **toCB**. With the code below the value is calculated if both the selections(**Kilometers** and **meters** are already made) and then I type a value in the **fromTB**. I want to make only one selection that is only the **fromCB** selection (**Kilometers**)and type value for it and the calculation should be done whenever I change the **toTB** selections(Meters , centimeters).

EDIT —
My current program runs this way :
1- I select Kilometers to convert from
2- I select Meters to convert to
3 - I put value in Convert from textbox
4 - The value is converted and shown in convert to textbox
I have to select both the selections first and then it converts.

How I want it to run :
1- I select Kilometers to convert from
2- I put the value to convert from
3- I select meters / centimetres to convert to ( I can change it continuously and I want the value to be converted with it )
4- Value is converted and shown in convert to textbox
Here I want to select one selection , put the value and the conversion should show as I change the second selection

EDIT 2-
Ok see my code is working it has no error , its just not working the way i want to. What I want to do is. I want to select kilometers in **fromCB** and then put a value in **fromTB**. Now this is my input. Now for my output as soon as I select any selection (for example - meters) in **toCB** , the value should populate automatically into **toTB** , and if I change my output selection (for example centimeters) , it should populate automatically in **toTB** again without altering the input. What my code is doing is , I have to select both selections(Km and cm) and then when I input any value , the output is populated and if i want to change the output selection(for example to meters) the output value does not change automatically , I have to input the value again

```
if (fromCB.SelectedItem == "Kilometers [km]")
            {
                

                if (fromTB.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a value to convert");
                }




                if(toCB.SelectedItem=="Meters [m]")
                {


                    float tb1;
                    float tb2;


                    tb1 = int.Parse(fromTB.Text);
                    tb2 = tb1 * 1000;

                    toTB.Text = tb2.ToString();

                }
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit about what the current problem is?

Comment: There is a good chance the question is "how to add the same handler to multiple dropdown controls". Could you please [edit] the question to clarify if that is the case.

Comment: I edited it to explain it more clearly now

Comment: @mihircodes Thanks for the update. Unfortunately it's still not clear what you are having trouble with. Why can't you make it work the way you want it to? And what have you tried?

Comment: @mihircodes Please check the answer and let me know.

Comment: I'll edit it more clearly

Comment: Is it more understandable now?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solution for you. You can use `SelectedIndexChanged` event for combobox. If you want update calculation on `textchanged` you can also use that update UI method. Please check the code->

```
public class MyType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
void LoadData()
{
    List<MyType> list = new List<MyType>();
    list.Add(new MyType() { ID = 1, Name = "Centimeter" });
    list.Add(new MyType() { ID = 2, Name = "Meter" });
    list.Add(new MyType() { ID = 3, Name = "KiloMeter" });

    fromCB.DataSource = list.ToList();
    fromCB.DisplayMember = "Name";
    fromCB.ValueMember = "ID";

    toCB.DataSource = list.ToList();
    toCB.DisplayMember = "Name";
    toCB.ValueMember = "ID";
}
private void fromCB_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateUI();
}
private void toCB_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateUI();
}
void UpdateUI()
{
    if (fromCB.SelectedItem != null && toCB.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        var fromID = ((MyType)fromCB.SelectedItem).ID;
        var toID = ((MyType)toCB.SelectedItem).ID;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fromTB.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fromTB.Text))
        {
            float value = -1;
            if (float.TryParse(fromTB.Text, out value))
            {
                if (fromID == toID)
                {
                    toTB.Text = value.ToString();
                }
                else if (fromID == 1 && toID == 2)
                {
                    toTB.Text = (value / 100).ToString();
                }
                else if (fromID == 1 && toID == 3)
                {
                    toTB.Text = (value / 100000).ToString("0.#########");
                }
                else if (fromID == 2 && toID == 1)
                {
                    toTB.Text = (value * 100).ToString();
                }
                else if (fromID == 2 && toID == 2)
                {
                    toTB.Text = value.ToString();
                }
                else if (fromID == 2 && toID == 3)
                {
                    toTB.Text = (value * 0.001).ToString();
                }
                else if (fromID == 3 && toID == 1)
                {
                    toTB.Text = (value * 100000).ToString();
                }
                else if (fromID == 3 && toID == 2)
                {
                    toTB.Text = (value * 1000).ToString();
                }
                else if (fromID == 2 && toID == 3)
                {
                    toTB.Text = value.ToString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Input is not a number");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** This is little bit long code. Please check if I missed something.

Comment: No worries bro , I got it to work . What I was doing was , I was coding into combo box selected index change , what I needed to do was code it into textbox value changed.